# Piecewise union of continuous maps is continuous

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, piecewise-continuity

**Q:** Suppose $X$ is a metric space and $A,B\subset X$; given continuous maps $f\colon A\to\Bbb R$ and $g\colon B\to\Bbb R$ which agree (ie, are equal) on $A\cap B$, prove that the piecewise union $h$ of $f$ and $g$ defined by $h(x)=f(x)$ when $x\in A$ and $h(x)=g(x)$ when $x\in B$ is continuous on $A\cup B$

**Attempt:**

Since $h\equiv f$ on $(A\cup B)\setminus B$ and $h\equiv g$ on $(A\cup B)\setminus A$, by continuity of $f$ and $g$, we conclude continuity of $h$ on $A\triangle B$. It remains to show continuity on $A\cap B$

Since $f(x)=g(x)$ on $A\cap B$, we can see $h$ as the restriction of $f$ (or $g$) on $A\cap B$ and we conclude since the restriction of a continuous map is continuous.

---

I feel like this proof might seem informal (read: not too rigorous). Is there any improvement I can make in the proof? Thanks!

Comment: Do you assume anything about $A$ and $B$? If not, take $X = \mathbb{R}$ with $A = \mathbb{Q}, B = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $f \equiv 1$ on $A$, $g \equiv 0$ on $B$ and see where your proof fails.

Comment: In these terms, the claim is false. For instance, consider $X=S^1=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x^2+y^2=1\}$, $A=\{(x,y)\in S^1\,:\, y\ge 0\}$, $B=\{(x,y)\in S^1\,:\, y< 0\}\cup\{(1,0)\}$, $f(x,y)=\arccos x$, $g(x,y)=-\arccos x$. Both functions are continuous, they agree at $(1,0)$, but the piecewise function is discountinuous at $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to assume $A$ and $B$ are both open *or* both closed.
Then it is a standard glueing lemma.
For other $A$ and $B$ things can go wrong.